# find: paths must precede expression: \+14

Tags: bash, find, sh

**This is the Error I am getting**

```
+ find /data/ing/ur/test -type f -iname -mtime '\+14' -exec mv '{}' /dm/Removed/$Removed_files ';'
find: paths must precede expression: \+14
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

**My .sh code**

```
export Removed_files=rmvfolder
export _searchStr="abc_*"
export _input_date='-mtime \+14'
mkdir -m777 /dm/Removed/$Removed_files
find /data/ing/ur/test -type f -iname $_searchSt $_input_date  -exec mv {} /dm/Removed/$Removed_files \;
```

Comment: There should be no need to `export` these variables, unless they are also used in code which you are not showing which depends on their values being made available to child processes of the current shell.

Comment: I would expect you to get an error more like `find: invalid argument `\+14' to `-mtime'` or `find: -mtime: \+14: illegal time value`

Answer (score 0):

You're messing with the shell's wildcard expansion, which will expand the expresion to all matching filenames in the given folder, thus passing several filenames to search for to `find` at once. Aside from that, I think you're misusing the `export` directive (aren't you?). You should modify your code as follows:

```
Removed_files=rmvfolder
_searchStr='abc_*' # Single quotes are needed here to prevent bash from expanding the wildcard!
_input_date='-mtime +14'
mkdir -m777 /dm/Removed/${Removed_files}
find /data/ing/ur/test -type f -iname ${_searchStr} ${_input_date}  -exec mv {} /dm/Removed/${Removed_files} \;
```

Alternatively, you can escape the asterisk; `_searchStr=abc_\*`

Comment: The braces are harmless but also useless here.

Comment: Yeah, I just use them by default in order to avoid surprises.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking find to locate files whose name matches (in a case insensitive match) the string `-mtime`, and then passing the string `\+14` as an argument that find is interpreting as a path.  It is telling you that the path must be given first.  The problem is that `_searchSt` is unset. (You set a variable named `_searchStr` earlier, so presumably this is a typo.)

Note that this problem would be avoided if you had used double quotes and written `find /data/ing/ur/test -type f -iname "$_searchSt" $_input_date  ...` . And this is a point of debate regarding best practice: you cannot double quote `$_input_date` since you are relying on field splitting here.  Best practice is probably to avoid relying on field splitting and explicitly writing `-mtime` with a variable containing just the argument to be used.  That is; `find "$path" -type f -iname "$searchStr" -mtime "$_input_date" ...`

You can also guard against this type of error (misuse of variable names) by using the `${..?}` construct and writing `find "${path?}" -type f -iname "${searchSt?}" ...`.